# Sort the Array by Descending using score value

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having difficulty showing the data I put in the array in descending order through the score. I've tried everything but without success. is there a way?
I fetch the data, name and score, from each player's firebase database, and then insert it into the array. When I want to show the name and score of each player in descending order, I don't see a way to do it, but if I add just the score to the array I can only show the descending score.

```
....
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
val names = arrayOf<String>()
val namesList = names.toMutableList()
for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
val name = userSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String::class.java)
val score = userSnapshot.child("score").getValue(String::class.java)
if (name != null && score != null) {
namesList.add("$name $score pts")
}
}
builder.setItems(namesList.toTypedArray()) { _, which ->
when (which) {
0 -> {
}

1 -> {
}
....
```

Comment: By saying you tried everything, what did you try exactly? There is literally no sorting in the provided code.

Comment: yes you are correct. I can only show it in descending order if I just add the score values to the array, and if I want to add the names and their scores, I don't see a way to do it in descending order. I wanted to see if the way I add the name and the score I could take the score and make it show descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options.

- first, as far as I can see you are using realtime database to order
  the data when they come in you can use this
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data?hl=es#sort_data
- Second, you can first get all the data from your database and then do a sort with kotlin
  https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by-descending.html